# Scraping a table without id with python and beautifulsoup

Tags: python, html, python-2.7, beautifulsoup

I am currently working on creating a telegram bot .
I now want to add the command `/drop Sorties`, but I need bs4 to scrape a table from an [this](https://www.warframe.com/repos/hnfvc0o3jnfvc873njb03enrf56.html) page.

The bot should answer something like

> ```
> Rifle Riven Mod   Rare (6.79%)
> Ayatan Anasa Sculpture    Uncommon (28.00%)
> 4000 Endo Uncommon (12.10%)
> etc etc etc..
> ```

I should define something in the code to look ONLY for user input in that defined page, and reply with the next table he find in that page.

Example html from the link provided above

```
<h3 id="sortieRewards">Sorties:</h3>
<table><tbody><tr><th colspan="2">Sortie</th></tr><tr><td>Rifle Riven Mod</td><td>Rare (6.79%)</td></tr><tr><td>Ayatan Anasa Sculpture</td><td>Uncommon (28.00%)</td></tr><tr><td>4000 Endo</td><td>Uncommon (12.10%)</td>
```

The bot should reply with the content of the table even if the input from the user is `Sortie` and not `Sorties:`

Comment: Welcome to SO. I tried my best to work out the essence of your question. It is still a little incoherent, but this is as much as I could do. So please consider rewriting your question based on my inputs. Please try to make your question short while still containing all the relevant information.

Comment: Thanks @LonelyNeuron , sorry if i wrote so much!
that's my first try, but the result is empty
`from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2
wiki = "https://www.warframe.com/repos/hnfvc0o3jnfvc873njb03enrf56.html"
header = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'} #Needed to prevent 403 error on Wikipedia
req = urllib2.Request(wiki,headers=header)
page = urllib2.urlopen(req)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page)

table = soup.find_all('Sorties')
print table`
This was for a local test, i can later adapt it for the telegram bot

Comment: @SHADOWSLIFER the problem is not that you wrote too much, but that what you wrote was irrelevant or duplicated

Comment: @SHADOWSLIFER please don't post code in the comments. if you want to add something to your question, use the [edit] button. If you have a new question, ask [ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'lxml')

sorties_header = soup.find('h3',{'id':'sortieRewards'})
sorties_table = sorties_header.find_next('table')

# First row is header. We need to skip it
for sortie in sorties_table.find_all('tr')[1:]:
    data = sortie.find_all('td')
    item = data[0].text
    drop_rate = data[1].text
    print(item,drop_rate)
```

The output is

```
Rifle Riven Mod Rare (6.79%)
Ayatan Anasa Sculpture Uncommon (28.00%)
4000 Endo Uncommon (12.10%)
```

Comment: Thanks!! it works without problems! i should now find a way to define user input in that code, to search the next table an user search for. How i can do it?

Comment: Scraping and reading user data and acting according to that data are different things. Sorry, i don't know how to help you with that.